# redirect user to a particular page after recieving notification in ngcordova push ionicframework android

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

is there a way with ionic to bring the user to a specific page or tab when opening the app through the notification?

I send the push,my phone is in background and the user accesses the app tapping on the notification just arrived. Actually the app opens the page which is already opened, but I want it opens a destination page chosen by notification.

```
// ------------------------------ GCM NG-CORDOVA PUSH-----------------------------------
.run(function($ionicPlatform,ngFB,$state,$cordovaPush,$rootScope,$ionicScrollDelegate, $cordovaMedia) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
var androidConfig = {
    "senderID": "XXXXXXXXXXX"
  };
 $cordovaPush.register(androidConfig).then(function(result) {
      // Success
      // alert(result);
    }, function(err) {
      // Error
      alert(err);
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function(event, notification) {
      //alert(notification.event);
      switch(notification.event) {
        case 'registered':
          if (notification.regid.length > 0 ) {
          // alert('registration ID = ' + notification.regid);
          }
          break;

        case 'message':

        $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('chatScroll').scrollBottom();
          // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
          //alert('message = ' + notification.message + ' msgCount = ' + notification.msgcnt);
         alert(JSON.stringify(notification));
          if (notification.foreground)
            {
                // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
               var soundfile = notification.soundname;
              // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.

              var media = $cordovaMedia.newMedia("/assets/www/"+ soundfile);
              media.play();
                alert(notification.payload.message);
            }
            else
            {
                window.location = '#/home';
                //$state.go('home');
            }
          break;

        case 'error':
          alert('GCM error = ' + notification.msg);
          break;

        default:
          alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
          break;
      }
    });



    // WARNING: dangerous to unregister (results in loss of tokenID)
   // $cordovaPush.unregister(options).then(function(result) {
      // Success!
    //}, function(err) {
      // Error
    //})


  });


})
```

Please Help me. Where i am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get some error? I see you commented out `//$state.go('home');` - did that not work?

Comment: i tried both  window.location = '#/home';
                $state.go('home'); no error nothing happens

Comment: Can you show us your router config please?

Comment: You can submit their states and router config

Comment: Is it okay if I pass some params when I call in and read those params when the notification arrives. I can redirect to any state after reading these param. Just wanted to know if this approach is correct?

Comment: yes i did that. you can pass any route param and go to state as per your param when notification arrives